# Remove WhiteSpaces Between BR tags

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I need to remove all whitespaces between BR tags

This is my String:

```
<br /> <br />  <br />    <br />
```

Output Should be:

```
<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Here is my Code:

```
$str = preg_replace("%<br />\s*<br />%", "<br />", $str);
```

This should work to my knowledge but I can't get it to work.

Any suggest should be appreciated.

Is for remove the spaces in wp tittle [http://mp3goo.com](http://mp3goo.com/), or is there any other way to clean the Title in wordpress?

Comment: What results are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more robust pattern.

```
\s*(<br ?\/?>)+\s*
```

It matches all the following:

- `<br>`
- `<br >`
- `<br/>`
- `<br />`

Usage:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\s*(<br ?\/?>)+\s*#', '<br />', $str);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
var_dump($str);
```

Output:

```
string(24) "<br /><br /><br /><br />"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137017)

Answer (score 1):

Since the tags are self-closing, you'll want to replace the white-space at either side.

```
$str = preg_replace("%\s*<br />\s*%", "<br />", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but, not works. Do you test it ?

Comment: @user3536517 It does work, http://3v4l.org/Zaor2. You've either given incorrect test data or you're doing something wrong.